# Is there a more elegant solution than f[a, b, Sequence@@#3,...]?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming, code-review

I am trying to construct a list of many possible combinations using `Outer` and `Permutations`. Something that looks like that:

```
Flatten@Outer[f[#3, a, Sequence @@ #1, Sequence @@ #2] &, 
  Permutations[{x, y}], Permutations[{w, t}], Range[3], 1]

{f[1, a, x, y, w, t], f[2, a, x, y, w, t], f[3, a, x, y, w, t], 
 f[1, a, x, y, t, w], f[2, a, x, y, t, w], f[3, a, x, y, t, w], 
 f[1, a, y, x, w, t], f[2, a, y, x, w, t], f[3, a, y, x, w, t], 
 f[1, a, y, x, t, w], f[2, a, y, x, t, w], f[3, a, y, x, t, w]}
```

Of course in my example the function `f` is an actual functions, there are more than two elements in the sets that need to be permuted, etc.

The `Sequence @@ #1` doesn't feel satisfying. It seems to me that there should be a way to avoid constructing lists and deconstructing them immediately. Is there a nicer (more "Mathematica-ish") way of writing this? I tried thinking of ways to use `Splice`, `Sequence` etc but nothing really worked.

Comment: If you defined `f`, you could define it in a way that is more convenient to use. Is that possible, or is `f` some function like `Plot` over which you have no control?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It seems to me that there should be a way to avoid constructing lists and deconstructing them immediately

Maybe there is a way to avoid lists, but I don't see the motivation. Lists are useful for gathering objects, and deconstructing them is cheap - calling `Sequence @@ someList` does not make a copy of all the elements in `someList` in general.

I do in general find pure functions filled with numbered slots and `Sequence @@` to be less readable than they could be. I would write a wrapper function that takes arguments in the form I have and shuffles them into the right order.

```
fHelper[{args1___}, {args2___}, arg3_] := f[arg3, a, args1, args2]
```

and then just call

```
Flatten@Outer[fHelper, Permutations[{x, y}], Permutations[{w, t}], 
  Range[3], 1]
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to dedicate this next answer to @JasonB, who doesn't like `#` signs:

```
ClearAll[f];
Flatten@Transpose[
   Outer[
    Apply[f] @* Flatten @* List,
    Range[3], {a}, Permutations[{x, y}], Permutations[{w, t}], 1],
   {4, 1, 2, 3}
   ];
% === orig 

(*  True  *)
```

:)

If you don't care about the ordering of the lists of `f[..]`, then `Transpose` may be omitted.

---

*Refactoring ideas (assuming `f` is user-defined)*

In what follows I'm making an assumption about the nature problem and `f`, based on a pattern inferred from only a single example. When I find myself facing a problem like the OP's, I usually think, somehow I've set this up the wrong way. In order to broaden the applicability of this Q&A beyond the rather narrow problem defined in the OP, I offer a few specific examples of approaches I sometimes use. (I was waiting for a reply to a comment, but it's time for me to move on.)

**Align argument patterns with argument data.**
Other than making the order of the arguments of `f` and `Outer` align better (as implied above), one way to address the problem is to define the function so that the permutations are passed to `f` as a combined list:

```
f[idx_, param_, x_List] := ...;
(* E.g.: *)
f[1, a, {x, y, w, t}]
```

If `a` or `1` is supposed to go in the list, then modify accordingly:

```
f[idx_,  x_List] := ...; (* f[1, {a, x, y, w, t}] or *)
f[x_List] := ...;        (* f[{1, a, x, y, w, t}]
```

Then combining the arguments in a flat list can be solved with `Flatten` or maybe `Join`.  If your data is in packed arrays, you can probably keep it that way and keep your computation efficient.

**Use subvalues.**
Another way is to use subvalues. In a sense, it serves a similar purpose as @JasonB's solution, but it keeps the definitions all attached to the symbol `f`.

```
f // ClearAll;
f[idx_, param_][args___] := f[idx, param, args];
Flatten@
 Outer[
  f[#3, a] @@ Join[#1, #2] &,
  Permutations[{x, y}], Permutations[{w, t}], Range[3], 1]
% === orig

(*  True  *)
```

Similarly, putting the `Join`/`Flatten` in `f`:

```
f // ClearAll;
f[idx_, param_][{args___}] := f[idx, param, args];
f[idx_, param_][args___] := f[idx, param]@Flatten@{args};
Flatten@
 Outer[f[#3, a][#1, #2] &,
  Permutations[{x, y}], Permutations[{w, t}], Range[3], 1]
% === orig

(*  True  *)
```

**Restructure input data inside `f[]`.**
A third approach is to flatten the permutations inside `f`:

```
f[idx_, param_, args___] := With[{permdata = Flatten@{args}},
   ...];
```

**Use named parameters instead of `#` (also use `Tuples[]`).**
Finally, if you want to keep `f` without changing it, then one could use a pure `Function` with named parameters.  Another change to consider is that `Tuples` seems a more natural fit than `Outer`. Here are two examples, one with `Outer` and one with `Tuples`:

```
Flatten@Outer[
  Function[{p1, p2},
   Table[f[idx, a, ##] & @@ Join[p1, p2], {idx, 3}]
   ],
  Permutations[{x, y}], Permutations[{w, t}], 1]

    
Function[{p1, p2, idx},
  f[idx, a, ##] & @@ Join[p1, p2]
  ] @@@ Tuples[{Permutations[{x, y}], Permutations[{w, t}], Range@3}]
```

Or to regress back to `#`:

```
f[#3, a, ## & @@ Join[#1, #2]] & @@@ 
 Tuples@{Permutations[{x, y}], Permutations[{w, t}], Range@3}
```

**Injection pattern.**
A bonus one, I guess, because I just thought of it as I was getting ready to submit. An injection pattern, somewhat in homage to @JasonB's solution, whose answer started this overly long ramble (Look, Ma! No `Flatten`! No `#`!):

```
Tuples@{Permutations[{x, y}], Permutations[{w, t}], Range@3} /.
  {{p1___}, {p2___}, idx_Integer} :> f[idx, a, p1, p2]
% === orig

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: I was gonna post @BobHanlon's solution, but he beat me to it. :)

Comment: very nice. I particularly like the Tuple in last paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

orig = Flatten@
   Outer[f[#3, a, Sequence @@ #1, Sequence @@ #2] &, 
  Permutations[{x, y}], Permutations[{w, t}], Range[3], 1];
```

Alternatively,

```
rev = Flatten@
   Outer[f @@ Flatten@{#3, a, #1, #2} &, Permutations@{x, y}, 
    Permutations@{w, t}, Range[3], 1];
```

The results are identical

```
orig === rev

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks. This isn't very different from what I already had, though.

Comment: It eliminated the use of `Sequence`

Answer (score 3):

Just for something different:

```
f @@@ Fold[Function[{x, y}, Join[x, x /. y]], 
  Table[{j, a, x, y, w, t}, {j, 3}], {{x -> y, y -> x}, {w -> t, 
    t -> w}}]
```

yields:

> {f[1, a, x, y, w, t], f[2, a, x, y, w, t], f[3, a, x, y, w, t],   f[1,
> a, y, x, w, t], f[2, a, y, x, w, t], f[3, a, y, x, w, t],   f[1, a, x,
> y, t, w], f[2, a, x, y, t, w], f[3, a, x, y, t, w],   f[1, a, y, x, t,
> w], f[2, a, y, x, t, w], f[3, a, y, x, t, w]}